# Value from HTML to another via registered element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm totally newbie when talking about HTML, so this can be obvious to you, but I hope you can help me.

We have a `top-menu.html` which have some dropdown menus. One of these menus is a checkbox menu.
I have to get the value (and the change event of it) in another HTML, the `index.html`.

There's a JS code registering an element that can be used by `index.html`. Still, I don't know how to retrieve the checkbox value.

`top-menu.html` JS:

```
function build_component() {

    var template = (document._currentScript || document.currentScript)
           .ownerDocument.querySelector('#top-menu-template'); 
    var topMenu = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    topMenu.createdCallback = function() {
        // import template into
        var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        this.appendChild(clone);
    };

    document.registerElement('page-top-menu', { prototype: topMenu });
}
```

Ok, so I can use `<page-top-menu>` in `index.html`. How to get `checkbox.checked` value now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery you can easily do this

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="check1">
```

jquery: You can use local storage to save your value

```
$('.check1').on('change',function(){

       var val1 = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem("value", val1);
       alert(val1);

    }
```

To retrieve that you can use following code remove it if you don't want any more

```
var valnew = localStorage.getItem("value");
alert(valnew);
localStorage.removeItem("value");
```

Comment: It does not work. I placed the jQuery code into `index.html` (the checkbox value must be used in it).

Comment: I edited the answer, I think you can use local storage for that.